# Bootstrap and CSS . offsetting comments trouble

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm running into a problem. I have a comments box with comments inside. Currently the comments width is set to the length of the comment body, with a max with of 50%.

When the user of the page creates a comment, the idea is to have the comment start from the right side of the box. To do this I have initially offset the @user's comment with bootstrap. The problem is that if the @user post a short comment, the comment is centered. I'd like it to match the style of a long @user comment.

[image]

```
<div class = "bubble_user col-md-offset-3 col-md-7" style = "width:    <%= comment.body.length %>%">
<%= comment.body %>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.bubble_user {
position: relative;
height: auto;
max-width: 50%;
margin: 14px;
  padding-top: 15px;
background: #6699FF;
border-radius: 7px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 13px 0px rgba(97, 97, 97, 0.89);
color: white;
}
```

Comment: I’d say, possible the simplest way would be to use an additional container element inside the column for that, and align that to the right side of the column … (Overwriting the `width` of actual bootstrap column elements is not a good idea IMHO, just likely to lead into troubles.)

Comment: this is so bad: `style = "width:    <%= comment.body.length %>%"` , is not good idea, and you aren't specify units (px, em, %, pt, pc, etc). To positioning the element just add float:right to the user comments.

Comment: Why is setting the width to the comment body length not a good idea? How should i adjust the width of the comment depending on the Comments body length?

Answer (score 0):

try to add "float" left or right  to css ...

```
 .bubble_user {float: right;}
```

Comment: I cannot add the float: right style because with bootstrap the column is getting set to float: left;